# CKEditor 5 / Laravel Livewire returns "null" even when there's content

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 5 as my WYSIWYG editor. It loads fine, looks perfect - however when I submit the form and try to get the contents of the editor it returns null.

My HTML Code:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="sendBulkEmail">
                            <div>
                                <textarea wire:model="message" class="form-control" id="ckeditor"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-alt-primary">
                                    Send Bulk Email
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                        <script>
                            ClassicEditor
                                .create( document.querySelector( '#ckeditor' ) )
                                .catch( error => {
                                    console.error( error );
                                } );
                        </script>
```

Controller:

```
    public $message;

    dd($this->message);
```

Any ideas to get the value in Livewire?

Looked over google, CKEditor Docs and other steps.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor will create a separate DOM element as a sibling of your chosen element, in this case #ckeditor (check in browser inspector). Your Livewire model binding is for the original textarea element, which never actually changes.

What you need to do is hook into the editors data change event, then send that data to Livewire using (for example) an event.

```
editor.model.document.on( 'change:data', () => {
    console.log( 'The data has changed!' );

    Livewire.emit('ckeditorChanged', editor.getData())
});
```